# Rate of Growth of pyramid structure.

Tags: data-analysis

This might be simpler than I'm making it out to be, but how can the growth rate of the pyramid structure be represented.

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \ / \
  4   5   6
 / \ / \ / \
7   8   9  10
```

- Firstly I thought its n+1 but that is only compared to the previous row, not the whole dataset.
- Then I though about binary trees (as each node branches into two others, but as they are interconected that doesn't work either).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed formula for [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), given by

$$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k = 1+2+3+ \dotsb +n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = {n+1 \choose 2}$$

Comment: I only wish i had more rep to upvote this.